# sed for replacting special characters with ""

Tags: regex, linux, parsing, sed

I try to parse the output of `terraform output` like this:

```sh
terraform output -json all_admins |
sed -e "s/,/;\n/g" -e "s/^(\[|\])//g"
```

```
terraform output -json all_admins
```

leads to:

```
["admin1@admin.com","admin2@admin.com"]
```

Current result:

```
terraform output -json all_admins |
sed -e "s/,/;\n/g" -e "s/^(\[|\])//g"
```

leads to:

```
["admin1@admin.com";
"admin2@admin.com"]
```

Exptected result:

```
"admin1@admin.com";
"admin2@admin.com"
```

How can I elegantly get rid off `[` and `]` with a regex in sed?

Comment: Use `jq` or another tool that speaks JSON.

Comment: I would love to, but `jq` is not installed on corporate workstations ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
terraform output -json all_admins | sed 's/[][]//g; s/,/;\
/g'

# Example:
s='["admin1@admin.com","admin2@admin.com"]'
echo "$s" | sed 's/[][]//g; s/,/;\
/g'

"admin1@admin.com";
"admin2@admin.com"
```

Make sure an unescaped `]` is placed at 1st position inside bracket position `[...]` and `[` is next.

Note that `sed 's/[][]//g' file` is equivalent of `sed -E 's/\]|\[//g' file`

Comment: That works, thank you.
Can you explain why this `'s/\]|\[//g'` works and why I must start with `]`?

Comment: That is rule of bracket expression that an unescaped `]` has to be placed right after opening `[` and `s/\]|\[//g` is alternation that can also be written as `'s/\[|\]//g'`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk`.

```
terraform output -json all_admins | 
awk -v RS='\\[|,|\\]' 'NF{$0=$0(RT==","?";":"");print}'
```

With shown samples output will be as follows.

```
"admin1@admin.com";
"admin2@admin.com"
```

***Explanation:*** Setting RS(record separator) as `[,]` for all lines. Then in main program checking condition if number of fields is NOT NULL and RT is `,` add `;` to current line else keep line same as it is, finally print the current line.